# Check if matchAll() is Defined in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typeof

I'm using Chrome and executing a piece of code where matchAll() is used in JavaScript. However, I only want to use this piece of code if matchAll() is defined, which it is not for Internet Explorer 11. And so I put a check on this like the following:

`if (typeof matchAll === 'function') {execute code using matchAll() }`

For some reason though, this check is not working and I'm simply trying to execute code when matchAll is defined as a function. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect you are looking for `String.prototype.matchAll()` rather than simply a function `matchAll()`

You can check for this like so:

```
if (typeof String.prototype.matchAll === 'function') { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

`matchAll` would be checking for a variable defined in the current, or global scope. What you are actually wanting to check for is if that method is on the `String` prototype.

Try this instead:

```
if (typeof String.prototype.matchAll === 'function') {execute code using matchAll() }
```